# Gallery requires a featured image but does not show it in posts/pages

Tags: php, images, themes, gallery, html

I've encountered a weird bug with my theme's gallery.

If I add a gallery, and do not specify a featured image, it will not show in the post/page. If I add a featured image, it will show the gallery but it will ignore the featured image.

I want to know what causes this? Perhaps I need to edit something in the media.php?

Comment: It may be your theme's functionality and not bug.

Comment: Yes. I'm considering that. Any idea what file calls these 'requirements'? So I can edit and fix.

Comment: Can you send me link of it so that i can help you in it.

Comment: You mean the link of the website as well as admin?

Comment: Link of website.

Comment: I'd agree that this is something to do with your theme's way of handling galleries, not the core gallery implementation. What theme are you using?